# Is the higgs metastability dependent on renormalization scheme?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, renormalization, higgs, unitarity

It is said that, in the absence of physics beyond the Standard Model (SM), the higgs potential

$$V_h= -\mu^2 \Phi^\dagger \Phi +\lambda (\Phi^\dagger \Phi)^2$$

becomes metastable (is unbounded from below) at high energies as the RG-running of $\lambda$ is such that $\lambda$ decreases as the energy scale increases, vanishing at a scale $\sim 10^{11} \mathrm{GeV}$ and becoming negative above that.

The running of $\lambda$ was calculated precisely in e.g https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.6497.

However, is this statement not dependent on the renormalization scheme?

Surely physically it should not be, but to see what I mean, consider something simpler than the SM Higgs, e.g just scalar $\phi^4$ theory.

$$V_\phi= m^2 \phi^2 +\lambda \phi^4$$
In the $\bar{\mathrm{MS}}$ scheme (based on dimmensional regularization), the $1$-loop $\beta$ function to the quartic vertex is positive and gives $\lambda$ a running of the form

$$\lambda(\mu) \sim \frac{1}{a-b\ln(\mu)}$$

with the energy scale $\mu$ with a Landau pole at some high energy.

In a renormalization scheme which imposes a hard UV momentum cutoff $\Lambda$ on loop integrals, at 1 loop $\lambda$ runs logarithmically with $ \Lambda$ but $m^2$ has a divergence like $-\lambda\Lambda^2$ (I believe the latter does not happen in $\bar{\mathrm{MS}}$, but would appreciate clarification on that?).  Thus for field values $\phi \sim \Lambda$ both terms of the potential would go as $\Lambda^4$ up to logarithmic corrections, so the mass term would compete with quartic, and for positive $m^2$ they would partially negate eachother.

One might then wonder if something similar would happen for the SM higgs, where the mass term would stabilize the negative quartic such that in fact there is no unbounded minimum of the potential as we go to high energies?

However, I feel that something in my $\phi^4$ example is wrong, that somehow the hard-cutoff and $\bar{\mathrm{MS}}$ schemes should give the same behavior for the potential in $\phi^4$ theory, but naively it doesn't look like that.